# BigQuery GA export schema: Product position (during impression) in a product list

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I wonder if anyone knows in which field will Google Analytics export the enhanced Ecommerce product position inside a list? It's being set to GA in ga('ec:addImpression', {'id': 'P12345',...,'list': 'Related Products',**'position': 1**}).. call

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

I basically need a query which will return positions for a product in a one or different lists.
Can't find the info here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Comment: I know others which complain similar thing, and my perception is that not all fields are exported. You may contact them as you are a premium user and ask them to add it.

Comment: I actually did. No response for a couple of days yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to agree with Pentium10; not *everything* that the GA pixel collects on the site is exported to BigQuery, although in my talks with Google reps, there is a roadmap for what will and will not be dumped into BigQuery for querying.

However, if you have access to the GA pixels on the page directly, or if you are using a tag management solution, such as GTM, you can alter the tags to gain this information. BigQuery does get all the custom dimensions that you have defined in the GA pixel as well as the GA property. Thus, you could change

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id': 'P12345',
            ...,
         'list': 'Related Products',
         'position': 1
         }
  )
```

to

```
ga('set', {
        'dimension1': 'P12345',
            ...,
         'dimension2': 'Related Products',
         'dimension3': 1
         }
  );
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This will set the aforementioned eCommerce variables that you are already sending to GA for reporting through the UI to custom dimensions tied to a specific scope (Hit, Session, User - You will need to define these when you create the custom dimension in the GA UI). This way, the custom dimensions will be exported to BigQuery such that they will tie to the specified scope.

Hopefully that helps!